# Rename [healthcare-finder] to [healthcare-finder-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 6 questions tagged both [healthcare-finder](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder) and [api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) — and I'm sure there are more to come.

I see two problems:

- The official name seems to be [*HealthCare Finder API*](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services)
- Most [healthcare-finder](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder) questions are not tagged with [api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api), which makes things inconsistent

Renaming [healthcare-finder](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder) to [healthcare-finder-api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder-api) and removing the redundant [api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) tags would solve both problems.

Any objections?