# Healthcare.gov linking to this site - ask them to update their site?

Tags: discussion, support

The US [Healthcare Finder API](https://finder.healthcare.gov/#services) is linking to this site:

> Have Questions? See if someone has already answered your question [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder), or [ask a new question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=healthcare-finder)

They use the [healthcare-finder-api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder-api) tag, and the tag info *here* at least explains something, but *nothing on their page* indicates that users are sent to an independent Q&A site.

Should we contact them with a request to at least update their page saying they are linking here?

How can this best be done? [We have the same issue with the Department of Labor at developer.dol.gov](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/editing-a-tags-name-wondering-about-us-gov-involvement-just-the-usual).
[An attempt to contact them with a request to update their page](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/a/357/4293) failed.

Comment: Is anyone from there answering questions or contributing to this site?

Comment: Minor comment: they use the [tag:healthcare-finder] tag, not the [tag:healthcare-finder-api] tag.

Comment: @philshem *[healthcare-finder-api] isanswered:1* returns 13 questions with answers. I went through the profiles of all 'answerers' (that includes you), but there's nothing there.

Comment: Maybe @jon-booth (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/3118/jon-booth), judging from [this answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/3298/4293)

Comment: @StanislavKralin Weird. That tag does not exist here. All the more reason to get that page fixed.

Comment: @JanDoggen, to your last comment: see [this question](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/rename-healthcare-finder-to-healthcare-finder-api#).

Comment: @JanDoggen DOL finally did get back to me, I apologize for not passing it along. Essentially the contact was 3rd party contractor, who had already moved on from the project. He said he would try and pass the information along...

Comment: @albert Thanks. Please add that under the other question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is snail mail. Write to the department head setting out your complaint and asking them to arrange contact with the correct person.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in these types of situations to simply reach out to the group pointing users here and hope they are responsive.

If/when they are unresponsive, try seeking out an underlying repository that the group/users rely on, ideally in GitHub. If one can be found, file an issue; there's no guarantee that they'll be more responsive than they haven't been, but at very least you've publicly filed and have done the due diligence.