# healthcare-finder-api tag

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions

16 unanswered questions with [healthcare-finder-api](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare-finder-api)

should we reach out to them? I found no email contact, just phone or mail/upload

https://www.healthcare.gov/contact-us/

Also found no appropriate github repo for posting as an issue (something we've done before)

https://github.com/CMSgov/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Healthcare.gov linking to this site - ask them to update their site?](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/healthcare-gov-linking-to-this-site-ask-them-to-update-their-site)